# Need to identify all rows meeting a complex logical condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, logical-operators

I have a datatable / dataframe with some columns of logical vectors - each logical vector represents the presence or absence of a species in a weekly survey. I want to identify those rows where the species is present over a 21 day period or more - the period that the species isn't recorded in between is irrelevant).

This means I need to identify all those rows where a 'TRUE' is present in at least 2 columns (only those columns with "detected" in the colname in example below) that are 3 or more columns apart (because each column represents a weekly survey).

So if e.g. V1 and V4 are TRUE, my 'result' column is TRUE. If only V6,V7,V8 are TRUE, my result column is FALSE. If V2 and V9 are TRUE, my result is TRUE etc.

This is part of a bigger simulation, and the number of columns in the dt (and the number of weekly surveys) varies depending on other simulation parameters, so it isn't possible to do it using column indexing. But the columns of interest can all be given the same suffix ('detected') as in the example code below.

There are also other TRUE/FALSE columns in the dt (that aren't suffixed with 'detected').

example data:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

#first column
colref <- 1:20

#number of columns will vary in the dt, so here we generate a random number 
n<-sample(5:10,1)

# function to create some logical vectors for the dt
create.col<-function(n){replicate(n,sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),20,replace=TRUE,prob = c(0.2,0.8)),simplify=FALSE)}

# create the dt
dt<-setDT(create.col(n))
# affix "detected" to columns of interest
colnames(dt) <- paste("detected", colnames(dt), sep = "_")
dt<-data.table(colref,dt)
dt

# need to create logical vector 'result' column identifying rows where TRUE is present in columns separated by three or more positions in the dt, with the 'detected' suffix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `melt` and `rle`:

```
melt(dt,id.vars="colref")[,.(detect=with(rle(value), 
                                        which.max(!values & lengths>=3)>1&sum(values)>1))                           
                          ,by=colref]

    colref   detect
     <int>   <lgcl>
 1:      1     TRUE
 2:      2     TRUE
 3:      3    FALSE
 4:      4    FALSE
 5:      5    FALSE
 6:      6    FALSE
 7:      7    FALSE
 8:      8     TRUE
 9:      9     TRUE
10:     10    FALSE
11:     11    FALSE
12:     12    FALSE
13:     13    FALSE
14:     14    FALSE
15:     15    FALSE
16:     16     TRUE
17:     17    FALSE
18:     18    FALSE
19:     19    FALSE
20:     20    FALSE
    colref detected
```

Comment: FYI, `.$value` and `.$length` are incomplete names; if you set `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)`, you should be warned about that. A 2-char code-golf adaptation: `with(rle(value), any(values & lengths>=3))`.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks, I wanted to make it short but `with `is definitely much more readable & cleaner ;-)

Comment: That's really useful, I didn't know about rle() - I think this is only counting rows with 4 consecutive TRUE values though, rather than also counting rows with TRUE values separated by >=3 columns but interspersed with FALSE values.

Comment: @davidj444, I noticed the same.. Given your input, which rows should have `result` column set to TRUE? (Rows 1,2,5,8,9, and 16)?

Comment: @davidj444: i think I misunderstood the question : `c(T,F,F,F,T)` would be a hit? Two `True` separated with at least 3 `F`

Comment: if previous assumption is OK, see my edit

Comment: Yes, that's right, assumption above is correct - any sequence where there are T 3 or more columns apart, so c(T,F,T,F,T,F,T) or c(T,F,F,F,T), but not c(T,T,T,F,F,F).

The concept is that the species is not mobile but has low detectability, so Fs in between Ts are assumed to be false Fs because surveyor does not detect the species on that visit.

Comment: thanks for feedback, updated code should work

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

check_three_apart <- function(x) {
  # for logical vector x, check if any TRUEs spaced at least 3 indices away
  spacing <- which(x) %>% diff()
  if (is_empty(spacing)) {
    return(FALSE)
  } else {
    return(any(spacing >= 3))
  }
}

dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(three_apart = select(., starts_with("detected")) %>% apply(1, check_three_apart))
print(dt)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, I'm getting the error message:

Error in apply(., 1, check_three_apart) : 'MARGIN' does not match dim(X)

when I run that code on e.g. the test dataset, though.

Comment: Hm.  It works for me running this code immediately after your own, even with fresh R session.  Do you have logical column with names starting with "detected?"

Comment: Thanks, my fault, there was a namespace clash with select(), it worked when I started a new session.

Answer (score 1):

I get a different result than the selected answer. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something in the OP's request.

```
unique(melt(dt, id="colref",measure=patterns("detected"),value.name = "result") %>% 
            .[, id:=1:.N, by=.(colref)] %>% 
            .[result==T] %>% 
            .[order(colref,variable), diff:=id-shift(id), by=.(colref)] %>% 
            .[diff>=3,.(colref,result)])[dt, on="colref"]
```

Output:

```
    colref result detected_V1 detected_V2 detected_V3 detected_V4 detected_V5 detected_V6 detected_V7
     <int> <lgcl>      <lgcl>      <lgcl>      <lgcl>      <lgcl>      <lgcl>      <lgcl>      <lgcl>
 1:      1   TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
 2:      2   TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
 3:      3     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE
 4:      4     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE
 5:      5   TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE
 6:      6     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE
 7:      7     NA       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
 8:      8   TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
 9:      9   TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
10:     10     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
11:     11     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
12:     12     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
13:     13     NA        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
14:     14     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
15:     15     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
16:     16   TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE
17:     17     NA        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
18:     18     NA        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
19:     19     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
20:     20     NA       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
```

Comment: This is the correct interpretation, yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just posting in case of interest - I compared the time of each solution - fixing the width of the dt to 8 logical vectors and testing for a dt with 20 rows (short.dt) and 2000 rows (long.dt). Everything else same as example above.

The fastest solution for the short dt is the slowest solution for the long dt, which is really interesting.

```
bm.long = microbenchmark(
  long.chk_3_apart = long.dt %>% mutate(three_apart = select(., starts_with("detected")) %>% apply(1, check_three_apart)),
  
  long.unique = unique(data.table::melt(long.dt, id="colref",measure=patterns("detected"),value.name = "result") %>% 
                    .[, id:=1:.N, by=.(colref)] %>% 
                    .[result==T] %>% 
                    .[order(colref,variable), diff:=id-shift(id), by=.(colref)] %>% 
                    .[diff>=3,.(colref,result)])[long.dt, on="colref"],
  
  long.melt = data.table::melt(long.dt,id.vars="colref")[,.(detect=with(rle(value),which.max(!values & lengths>=3)>1&sum(values)>1)),by=colref]
)
bm.short = microbenchmark(
  short.chk_3_apart = short.dt %>% mutate(three_apart = select(., starts_with("detected")) %>% apply(1, check_three_apart)),
  
  short.unique = unique(data.table::melt(short.dt, id="colref",measure=patterns("detected"),value.name = "result") %>% 
                         .[, id:=1:.N, by=.(colref)] %>% 
                         .[result==T] %>% 
                         .[order(colref,variable), diff:=id-shift(id), by=.(colref)] %>% 
                         .[diff>=3,.(colref,result)])[short.dt, on="colref"],
  
  short.melt = data.table::melt(short.dt,id.vars="colref")[,.(detect=with(rle(value),which.max(!values & lengths>=3)>1&sum(values)>1)),by=colref]

  )

bm.long
Unit: milliseconds
             expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 long.chk_3_apart 23.9713 28.10315 30.72980 28.97950 33.56685  42.4375   100
      long.unique 29.0775 33.97245 37.18426 35.78765 40.09710  53.4566   100
        long.melt 46.0760 51.91215 56.63633 55.82730 58.76905 112.5073   100

> bm.short
Unit: microseconds
              expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 short.chk_3_apart 2620.7 2979.55 3666.362 3295.95 3662.30 12386.6   100
      short.unique 3716.9 4261.35 4697.893 4382.30 4804.35 11289.2   100
        short.melt  941.5 1078.95 1161.753 1137.45 1214.90  1749.4   100
```